# Two sets of odd primes such that their sum of $k$th powers equal each other

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider a set of odd primes, $S= \{p_1 , p_2 , p_3 ,\cdots , p_n\}$.

With an integer input $k>2$, is it possible to come up with two sets $A,B\subseteq S$ (with $A\neq B$) such that

$$\sum_{p\in A} p^k=\sum_{q\in B} q^k$$

Also what will happen if I enforce these sets A and B to have the same cardinality?

Comment: If you have $|A|, |B|=2$ then this shouldn't be possible as the Gaussian integers are a UFD (so there can only be one representation of a number as a sum of two squares). I would try and play around modulo $p$ and consider Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Thanks for editing and also your comment. well their cardinality can be equal up to 1000 elements. And to be honest my main question is a bit different and this is the simplest case. the main question consider this in a modulo setting. Which means I have a random huge prime T. and i want those summations modulo T be equal to each other.

Comment: Are you just asking for an individual example, say, $6379^5+3833^5+2657^5=6089^5+5003^5+1777^5$?

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be possible depending on the primes, $k$, etc.

If you have $n$ primes then you can form $2^n$ subsets. So very very roughly if the sum of $p^k$ is less than $2^n$ then chances are that you find two subsets with the same sum.

You said “up to 1000 primes”. That’s not much less than $2^{1000}$ subsets of 500 elements. If $k >= 1000$ then it may be impossible - the largest prime to the $k$th power might be larger than all other powers' sum. Same for $100$th powers of very large primes, but say $12$th powers of the first 1000 primes can likely be split into two subsets.

Now *finding* two subsets with a significant number of elements will be very, very difficult. There is a pseudo-polynomial solution in $O(n)$ - buy an expensive computer and create a sieve for all sums $<= 10^{12}$. That works for $k=4$ and primes $<= 1000$, or $k=5$ and primes $< 250$. For larger primes you could create a sieve for sums $n$ for $10^{12}$ different values of n mod $10^{12}$, and examine further if you find matches.

PS. Assuming you ask about two non-empty subsets with no common elements, you can easily prove no subset contains the prime 2, no subset contains 3 if $k$ is even, and probably other conditions.